# random walk position generation still generates duplicates even though there is a duplicate checker

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, procedural-generation, random-walk

As the title says, I created a random walk position generator for our dungeon crawler game. But everytime i generate a room, there is still a duplicate position generated even though there is a duplicate checker (located at posGenerator() while loop). Sometimes it generates good (no duplicate positions) and sometimes it generates duplicates.

Any ideas and opinions are welcomed. Thanks!

[image: Vector2 position logs (duplicate generation)]

[image: Vector2 position logs (no duplicate generation)]

posGenerator()

```
public void posGenerator() {
        Vector2 currentPosition = transform.position;
        positionList.Add(currentPosition);
        for(int i = 0; i < roomCount; i++){
            int currentDirection = RandomNumberGenerator();
            currentPosition = directionalPosition(currentPosition, currentDirection);
            while(positionList.Contains(currentPosition)){  // keep generating position until a new position is generated
                currentPosition = generateNewPosition(positionList[i], currentDirection);
            }
            positionList.Add(currentPosition);
            if(i+1 == roomCount){
                for(int j=1;j<positionList.Count;j++){
                    Debug.Log("Position " + j + ": " + positionList[j]);
                    directionList.Add(generateDirectionList(positionList[j-1], positionList[j]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

generateNewPosition()

```
public Vector2 generateNewPosition(Vector2 position, int direction) {
        int[] excludeDirections;

        switch (direction) {
            case 1: excludeDirections = new int[] { 2, 3, 4 }; break;
            case 2: excludeDirections = new int[] { 1, 3, 4 }; break;
            case 3: excludeDirections = new int[] { 1, 2, 4 }; break;
            default: excludeDirections = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }; break;
        }

        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, excludeDirections.Length);
        int newPosition = excludeDirections[randomIndex];
        return directionalPosition(position, newPosition);
    }
```

I tried changing the structure of while loop, tried using if else and refactoring my code. Still doesnt work. I expect no duplicate positions

Comment: What is directionalPosition? And print vector with `.ToString("f7");`

Comment: directionalPosition determines where to go (left,right,up or down), indicated as int. also i use vector2 for computation of x and y not sure if it'll work well

Comment: i suggest to log currentPosition when go out the while  loop and check if you enter effectively in the while loop...

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert in unity, but it seems your error comes from this line:

```
    Vector2 currentPosition = transform.position;
    positionList.Add(currentPosition);
```

at each time you enter in this method, you add `currentPosition` to the list...but following your program, `currentPosition` is already in the list...so you add a duplicate.(except the first time you enter, the list is empty) so just add to the list only if the list is empty...

Comment: it still generates duplicate positions :(

Comment: @mpbstrd, ok i believe i have understood why you have duplicate..see my answer